# How to assign values to a 2D array in a loop?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a 1D array of options and a 1D array of answers, 3 options and 1 answer for each question. I want to be able to randomize the positions of each row of `$randomOption`, so that's why I am trying to put it in a 2D array. I'm not sure how to do this, though.

```
$randomOption = array();

For($x = 0; $x=$noQuestions-1; $x++){
    $randomOption[$x,$x*4] = $options[$x*3];
    $randomOption[$x,$x*4+1] = $options[$x*3+1];
    $randomOption[$x,$x*4+2] = $options[$x*3+2];
    $randomOption[$x,$x*4+3] = $answer[$x];

    echo $randomOption[$x, $x*4];
    echo $randomOption[$x, $x*4+1];
    echo $randomOption[$x, $x*4+2];
    echo $randomOption[$x, $x*4+3];
}
```

Comment: WHat is the expected output? Also add the input arrays.

Comment: What is `$noQuestions` ?

Comment: What is the comma in in the key name `[$x, $x*4]` suppose to do? (as it is, it will give you a parse error).

Comment: @Tiger It holds the number of questions. It's -1 in the loop because of how I programmed it.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson It's just me trying to create a 2d array. I'm not sure how to do it though.

Comment: @Kurt Görg , Did you try my code?

Comment: @AbhayMaurya Hi. Your code looks like it would work, but I do not have a set number of questions for my quiz, therefore I'm not sure how to create your first line of code. Could I use a loop somehow?

Comment: @Kurt Görg How questions are coming? Can you tell me anyhow from where you are taking your questions and how?

Comment: @AbhayMaurya My program is quite complex. I have a 'test creator' page and that allows a user to enter a question, an answer, and 3 other options multiple times under a quiz name. Is there any other way I can create the multiple dimension array from your first line?

Comment: @Kurt Görg I have updated my answe, you can take combination of question,options and answer in an array like in my answer in $question_option_answer_array, Please check the updated answer ans see if it works for you.

Comment: @Kurt Görg . Please accept the answer to close this question if you have got the idea how to make your code. Thanks,

Comment: @AbhayMaurya Sorry there has been a misunderstanding. My fault. I want to put the answer and the options together and randomise it, so it's like a multiple choice test where you do not know the answer. My bad :(

Comment: Good luck with your quest. I tried my best to help you as far as possible.

Comment: @AbhayMaurya that's fine. You gave me a good idea on what I have to do. Thanks.

Comment: @Kurt Görg, Feel free to accept the answer as its about what you have initially asked and anyone else who have same problem can get a guideline. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Man, i dont know what kind of code you have written there but I got your idea, what you want to do. Here is a working code:

```
// I assume you have some array with questions,their options and answers in it like : array(question, option_array, answer)
$question_option_answer_array = array(array('question1',array('a','b','c'),'a'), array('question2',array('A','B','C'),'B'), array('question3',array('I','II','III'),'I'));
$noQuestions = count($question_option_answer_array);
$options = array();
$answers = array();
for($i=0;$i<$noQuestions;$i++){
  $options[] = $question_option_answer_array[0][1];
  $answers[] = $question_option_answer_array[0][2];
}
$options = array(array('a','b','c'),array('A','B','C'),array('I','II','III'));
$answers = array('a','B','I');
$limit = count($answers);
$mixArray = array();
for($i=0;$i<$limit;$i++){
  shuffle($options[$i]);
  echo 'My Options :<br>';
  foreach($options[$i] as $op){
    echo $op.'<br>';
  }
  echo 'My answer :'.$answers[$i].'<br><br>';
}
```

One example output:

```
My Options :
c
a
b
My answer :a

My Options :
A
C
B
My answer :B

My Options :
III
II
I
My answer :I
```

It will change every time as you want.
It organizes your options randomly every time and your answer remain intact relative to every set of option as its in different array. Use `$options` array to give your options and `$answers` array to store your answer respectively.

*I hope it helps*